Fade out animation on Popup React js
I am currently using react and I have a popup modal that I am trying to animate and i can get the fade in animation working but I can't get it to fade out. Is this possible to do?
Here is my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { X } from 'lucide-react';

const Links = () => {
  const [ showLink, setShowLink ] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowLink(!showLink)
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='links-div'>
      ...
      <div className='link-images'>
        <div className='image-one'>
          ...
        </div>

        <div className='image-two' onClick={handleClick}>
          <img
            src='../../../images/delivery_link_image.png'
            width={300}
            height={300}
          />
          <p>DELIVERY</p>
        </div>
        
        {showLink && (
            <div 
              className='delivery no-scroll'
              style={{animation:'appear .3s linear'}}
            >
              <div 
                className='close'
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={{animation:'disappear .3s linear'}}
              >
                <button 
                  className='close-button'
                > 
                  <X size={40}/>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        
        <div className='image-three'>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Here is my CSS code:
/* Pop-up selectors for Delivery link */
/* backdrop */ 
.delivery {
  background: hsl(48, 54%, 89%, 50%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  z-index: 102;
}

.delivery, body:has(.no-scroll) {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: hidden;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  } 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* This selector below is to make the popup disappear but does not work */
@keyframes disappear {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Closing popup selectors */
.close {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

.close-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button:active {
  height: 80%;
  transform: scale(0.90);
  position: relative;
  top: -0.10em;
  left: -0.09em;
  box-shadow: .5px .5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 10%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: -2em;
}

I added a 'disappear' name for the @keyframes animation but it does not work. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

There is no actual way to play an animation when something is removed from DOM tree without any thrid party library, mainly because, if it is not in the DOM anymore, there's nothing to animate. But you can use some tricks to have it running.

trust me, don't go down this insane mans rabbit hole. just use a 3rd party library like framer motion to animate presence. I've been where you stand and i did stuff I'm not proud of nor will i ever disclose
